# What is the relation between the amount of data transmitted and line distance?

Tags: computer-networks

I am wondering what is the relation between line distance and the amount of data transmitted on that line. I know only the basic of computer science. Let's say I want to calculate the time it takes for 100 GB to transfer over a line with the speed of 100MBps. If I just divide them, I will get 1000 seconds but in my online class, the lecturer said the time depends on the line distance. Since it is an introductory course, he doesn't explain anymore. So my question is, how is it relevant and why? I know the simple answer should be the resistance of the line increase as it got longer but does the resistance affect on the needed time significantly? How could I calculate the needed time with distance?

Comment: Beware differences between *bits*, *bytes* (and possibly *octets*).

Comment: If you are on earth and the receiver on the moon, add about 1.3 seconds to the time :-)

Comment: If the only data that was given are the total size and the transfer rate, there is nothing else that you can say. If you ignored other data, the guilt is yours.

Comment: The most important distinction to draw in general is between *throughput* (the amount of data you can transmit and receive per time unit) and *latency* (the delay with which transmitted data will be received). Often, they are determined by completely different factors.

Answer (score 1):

With the size of data and bandwidth given, you can only calculate the **transmission delay** and not the **propagation delay**(latency). The latter depends on the physical characteristics of the medium used for transfer of data.

Answer (score 0):

Distance sets lower bounds on *latency*, the effect on *throughput* as opposed to *data rate* depends on *protocol*.
Raw error rate increases with distance.

Comment: Coincidentally, EM signals take, on average, 499 seconds to travel between earth and sun. The moon has successfully been used as a reflector - if it was possible to have signals reflected at some "surface" of the sun, 1000 seconds from transmission start to reception end would amount to *something*, while half an hour couldn't possibly get you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> I know the simple answer should be the resistance of the line increase as it got longer but does the resistance affect on the needed time significantly?

but this is not about the resistance of the line.

Consider again the statement

> the lecturer said the time depends on the line distance

So the question is how long it takes to transfer/communicate $X$ amount of data (100 Gbit, let's say) if the line speed is 100 MBit/s). You think it may be just 1000 s (amount of data divided by line speed).

But the point about the line distance is that it takes a finite amount of time for the transmission to go through the line. This is called *latency*. For example, if it takes 10 s to go through the line, then the answer is 1000+10s = 1010s.

Knowing both the data rate (line speed) and latency (line distance), allows you to answer the question of how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

100 Gigabyte at 100 Megabyte per second will always take 1,000 seconds. That's computer science (taking the expression generously).

But then there is physics. It is harder achieving a certain bitrate over a long distance. Usually when you send a signal through cables, you have a quality loss at the initial connector at the source, you have loss at the final connector at the destination, and you have a loss of signal for every meter of distance. At some point the total loss of signal quality is so high that you can't transmit your 100 Megabyte per second anymore.

You can use higher quality parts, better connectors, better (more expensive) cables. That lets you transmit at the same speed over a longer distance. You can avoid laying your cable close to power lines, or bending your cables - if you need to change direction of the cable by 90 degrees do it in a gentle curve. All these methods let you transmit 100 Mbyte per second over a longer distance.

If that's not enough, you have two choices: Reduce the bitrate, or reduce the distance. A 50 Megabyte per second bitrate will work over a longer distance. So the longer distance doesn't make the bitrate slower, what it does is it reduces the highest bitrate that works. And a shorter distance increases the highest bitrate that works.

If you need more distance, you can insert amplifiers into the cable that will refresh a low quality digital signal into a higher quality one.

(There is a very small range where your quality is just low enough to introduce errors, but still high enough to fix or detect the errors. If you detect the errors, you'll have to ask the other side to retransmit the data. So your rate of *useful* bytes transmitted per second goes down).